# How to pass arguments to saved SBCL core?

Tags: compilation, common-lisp, sbcl

I have a Lisp (SBCL 1.0.40.0.debian) application (myfitnessdata), which uses the following code to process command line arguments:

```
(:use :common-lisp)
(:export #:main))

(in-package :myfitnessdata)

(require :sb-posix)

;; snip

(defun main ()
  (if (= (length sb-ext:*posix-argv*) 3)
    (let ((username (nth 0 sb-ext:*posix-argv*))
      (password (nth 1 sb-ext:*posix-argv*))
      (path (nth 2 sb-ext:*posix-argv*)))
      (scrape (username password path)))
    (show-usage)))
```

I am compiling this application using the following Lisp code:

```
(load "myfitnessdata.lisp")
(save-lisp-and-die "myfitnessdata.bin" :executable t :toplevel 'myfitnessdata:main)
```

This produces an executable that I can run.  However, the `sb-ext:*posix-argv*` list is always empty.  If I run the following:

```
./myfitnessdata.bin myusername mypassword /home/me/data
```

... then all I get is the usage instructions produced by `(show-usage)`.

I think I must be missing something simple again - could someone please let me know how to `(save-lisp-and-die)` such that the resultant executable takes command line arguments?

Comment: Upon reflection I suspect that what save-lisp-or-die is doing is saving the command line arguments that were passed into the SBCL instance. So, when the core is loaded, the command line argument list is empty.  No idea how to work around that though ...

Comment: Duncan, I'm nearly 100% sure your comment above is incorrect. As mentioned on the mailing list late last night, the problem with your code was that the first argument is the name of the executable that was called. Just change the 3 to a 4, the 0 to 1, etc, in your code above. I think this is important to point out, because while buildapp etc might be great, they aren't required to solve your specific problem here.

Comment: Oh, you also cut off the defpackage in your code.

Comment: Dan - I'm nearly 100% sure too :-)  After switching to buildapp (which I'm sticking with as it makes life easier) I had to make the change you mentioned to get things working.  It's obviously been too long since I've done any serious C programming ;-)

Comment: FYI: SBCL on Linux is at x.45.x while you're at 40.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, as suggested by the good folks on [sbcl-help](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=sbcl-help), is to use a tool like [buildapp](http://www.xach.com/lisp/buildapp/) to compile the app.  You can specify an entry point, which is assumed to be a function with one argument.  At run-time, that function is called with a list of command-line parameters.

Using buildapp, my `main` function is now:

```
(defun main (args)
  (if (= (length args) 4)
      (let ((username (nth 1 args))
           (password (nth 2 args))
           (path (nth 3 args)))
    (scrape username password path))
    (show-usage)))
```

Comment: You should fix your indentation.  Also, you could use `destructuring-bind` instead of `let` here.

Comment: I posted a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11208251/how-to-use-buildapp-with-a-pre-defined-asd-file) considering the practical usage of buildapp, I would appreciate if you could take a look at it.