# How to use buildapp with a pre-defined asd file

Tags: common-lisp, executable, sbcl

I intend to use [buildapp](http://www.xach.com/lisp/buildapp/#example) for getting executables out of my lisp-code, but I do not understand how I can specify my .asd file for the project, for loading up the code.

I imagined some call like:

```
buildapp --asdf-file:/path/to/projectasdffile.asd \
         --entry-point package:main
```

But the examples provided by the homepage do not cover a call I recognize as equal,  all the example calls look like a whole asdf definition itself. This would be a bit big for a whole project, especially as I already got a whole project definition (using asdf).

Therefore: Is there a way to use buildapp like the imaginary example call provided?

Comment: did you look at `--load-system` key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`buildapp --load-path /path/to/project --load-system project` should do the trick.

Comment: yes it does but you might want to add that any other needed asd file must be provided in that folder as well

Comment: You can use any number of --load-path arguments to point to other system files.